# custom contrasts in emtrends

Tags: r, emmeans

With this this example data set

```
dat <- data.frame(sample=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14), treatment=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), condition=factor(c("A","A","A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")), scores=c(2,4,3,5,6,13, 41,30,30,23,24,24,10,8))
mod <- lm(scores~treatment*condition, data=dat)
```

I set up custom contrasts to look at a linear increase for `condition A` across `treatment`, and linear decrease for `condition B` across `treatment` variable:

```
con <- matrix(c(contr.poly(6)[,1],rep(0,8),rep(0,6),contr.poly(8)[,1]*-1), ncol=2)
con
            [,1]        [,2]
 [1,] -0.5976143  0.00000000
 [2,] -0.3585686  0.00000000
 [3,] -0.1195229  0.00000000
 [4,]  0.1195229  0.00000000
 [5,]  0.3585686  0.00000000
 [6,]  0.5976143  0.00000000
 [7,]  0.0000000  0.54006172
 [8,]  0.0000000  0.38575837
 [9,]  0.0000000  0.23145502
[10,]  0.0000000  0.07715167
[11,]  0.0000000 -0.07715167
[12,]  0.0000000 -0.23145502
[13,]  0.0000000 -0.38575837
[14,]  0.0000000 -0.54006172
```

Is it possible to compute these contrasts with `emmeans`?

I know I can do `emm <- emtrends(mod, ~ condition, var="treatment")`, which fits a linear function, but what if I'd like to use my custom contrasts, can they be incorporated into `emtrends`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using

```
contrast(emm, con)
```

That's because `emtrends()`, like `emmeans()`, returns an object of class `emmGrid`, which is what `contrast()` can work with.

By the way, polynomial contrasts are available via a built-in function, so they don't require a custom setup. You can do something like

```
contrast(emm, "poly", max.degree = 3)
```

#### addendum

Oops, I overlooked the fact that `con` is a matrix. You need to first re-create it as a named `list` with each element being the desired contrast coefficients. Or a `data.frame` with the contrast coefficients as columns.

Comment: Thanks @RussLenth! `contrast(emm, con)` gives me an error: `Nonconforming number of contrast coefficients`. I suspect you meant I should do `contrast(emm, list(c1=c(-1,1)))`, which gives me the difference in estimates between `condition A` and `condition B` with respect to `treatment`. My question, however, was how to compute manual contrasts *separately* for `condition A` and `condition B` as a function of `treatment`. Is this possible with `emmeans`?

Comment: The closest I get is with `summary(emt, infer=c(TRUE,TRUE))` which gives me separate estimates for `condition A` and `condition B` as a function of `treatment`, but these are based on the linear fit, not on my own custom contrasts

Comment: Show the code for fitting `mod`

Comment: Thanks for your help @RussLenth. Do you mean this `mod <- lm(scores~treatment*condition, data=dat)`?

Comment: It looks to me like `confint(emm)` already gives you estimates of the linear trends you wish to estimate with those contrasts.

Comment: Yes, `confint(emm)` gives me the linear trends. I'd just like to understand how I can use my own contrasts, because I'd like to test more unconventional contrasts. I just thought I'd use linear contrasts in my example as they are easier to set up and to compare with the built-in functions.

Comment: For example, let's say I wish to get the estimate of a linear increase for condition `A` and linear decrease for condition `B` (across `treatment`), and have the coefficients in the *same* contrast:
`con <- list(c1=c(contr.poly(6)[,1], contr.poly(8)[,1]*-1))`. I'm not sure it's possible to test this using built-in functions, is it?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying an entirely different answer now that I know more from a few comments.

In the OP, we have a test dataset `dat` to which we have fitted the model below, and obtained estimated trends

```
mod <- lm(scores ~ treatment*condition, data = dat)
emt <- emtrends(mod, ~ condition, var = "treatment")   # I renamed it
```

Here are the estimates, and a direct comparison of those estimates:

```
> emt
 condition treatment.trend    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A                    1.80 0.805 10  0.00604     3.59
 B                   -4.14 0.520 10 -5.30085    -2.98

Confidence level used: 0.95 

> pairs(emt)
 contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 A - B        5.94 0.958 10   6.201  0.0001
```

From a comment:

> let's say I wish to get the estimate of a linear increase for condition A and linear decrease for condition B (across treatment)...

I believe that the above comparison of trends does exactly that. The difference of slopes is estimated to be 5.94. By the way, you can get this estimate without using anything in the **emmeans** package:

```
> summary(mod) $ coefficients
                      Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          -0.800000  3.1355565 -0.2551381 8.037871e-01
treatment             1.800000  0.8051366  2.2356456 4.936755e-02
conditionB           43.192857  4.0889261 10.5633745 9.597218e-07
treatment:conditionB -5.942857  0.9583042 -6.2014308 1.012643e-04
```

Note that the estimate and test for `treatment:condition` is exactly the same.

But continuing the comment:

> ... and have the coefficients in the same contrast: con <- list(c1=c(contr.poly(6)[,1], contr.poly(8)[,1]*-1))

First of all, this is a contrast of the *means*, not the slopes. Second, I definitely do not think this is what you want, because you are putting the slope for treatments 1--6 on one scale, and for treatments 7--14 on another.

If you want it all in one contrast and on the same scale, use `emmeans` (*not* `emtrends`) to estimate the means at two different treatment values (say 5 and 6) and two conditions, and construct the appropriate contrast:

```
> EMM <- emmeans(mod, ~ treatment*condition, at = list(treatment = 5:6))
> contrast(EMM, list(con = c(c(-1, 1), -c(-1, 1))))
 contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 con          5.94 0.958 10   6.201  0.0001
```

This works because the model fits straight lines which have the same slopes regardless of the value of `treatment`, and the slope is equal to the difference in predictions for two treatments spaced one apart.

Comment: Thanks @RussLenth! I perfectly understand that `emt` is already showing the linear effects I mention in the question. My persistence in computing them manually is only for my understanding, so that I'll be able to apply different contrasts that may not have built in functions. Let me put another way: the slope for `treatment` when `condition==A` is equal to `1.8`. Can you somehow use the first manual contrast in my question `list(c1=c(contr.poly(6)[,1], rep(0,8)))` in `emmeans`/`emtrends` (or plain `R`) in order to get the same estimate of `1.8`?

Comment: For the second part of your answer, let me give you a more concrete example. Let's say these are data from one subject (I'll ignore the dependence in observations) and that `treatment` really refers to time during treatment in either condition `A` or `B`. I predict that `condition A` causes scores to increase across time, but `condition B` reduces scores as time progresses. So a contrast like `con <- list(c1=c(contr.poly(6)[,1], contr.poly(8)[,1]*-1))` is intended to test this increase-followed-by-decrease effect on scores. Does that make sense?

Comment: In other words, with the latter comment, I don't want estimates of the individual slopes for condition `A` and `B`, nor do I wish to compare the slopes with one another. What I'd like is to test the the combined up-and-down effect across the entire `treatment` variable.

Comment: It looks from here like you are trying to achieve something that can be done very simply by doing something very elaborate. Trying to be too fancy increases the chances of doing something wrong, and I have no interest in supporting that. And I have already explained why that elaborate contrast of yours is not useful. I have nothing more to contribute here.

Comment: @locus I had the thought that maybe you want the total amount of change. If you have hourly data and a line with slope s then the total change over a span of 6 hours is 6s. Then another 8 hours with negative slope t so the change is -8t, and the combined change is 6s - 8t. We can estimate this with the `emtrends` result above and  `contrast(emt, list(chg = c(6, -8)))`.

Comment: that's great! Yes, I'll try that contrast on my real data set! Many thanks for your help!